# Changing a normal grid into a grid with RowExpander

Tags: extjs, grid, panel

So I have the working view here that creates my grid just fine.

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',
    title: '<center>Results</center>',
    store: 'User', 
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        dock: 'bottom',
        items: [
            { xtype: 'tbtext',  text: 'Loading...', itemId: 'recordNumberItem'  },
            '->',
            { text: 'Print', itemId: 'print' },
            '-',
            { text: 'Export', itemId: 'export' }
        ]
    }],
    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', flex: 4, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'ID', dataIndex: 'ID', flex: 2, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'Mid Name', dataIndex: 'mid_name', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'Last Name', dataIndex: 'last_name', flex: 4, tdCls: 'grid_cell'},
            {header: 'Address', dataIndex: 'adress', flex: 3, tdCls: 'grid_cell'}
        ];
        this.callParent(arguments); //Calls the parent method of the current method in order to override 

        var store = this.getStore(); //Retrieving number of records returned
            textItem = this.down('#recordNumberItem');
            textItem.setText('Number of records: ' + store.getCount());

            //var val = Ext.getCmp('criteria_1').getValue();
            //store.filter('ID', val); 

    }   
});
```

I want to transform each row in the grid to be expandable and collapsable, like shown here in the Sencha Docs under Row Expander: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/

I have tried adding plugins but cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: you should include the plugins code that you tried and explain what "cannot get it to work" means. unexpected behavior? throws exception?

Answer (score 3):

Use the plugins config like so:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List',{
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   //other configs
   plugins: [{
      ptype: 'rowexpander',
      rowBodyTpl: ['{field}']
   }]
});
```

See a working example [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Litote0707/xPpf2/). Also, Sencha Docs provides a "Code Preview" panel on the right that shows the code they used.

I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11712262/640030) that you can't configure plugins within initComponent, though that was for ExtJS 4.1 when rowexpander was still ux. I'm not sure of its relevance in 4.2.

Comment: i need in second grid row rowBodyTpl please help me

Answer (score 2):

This is super late, but for anyone that needs another row:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List',{
   extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
   //other configs
   plugins: [{
      ptype: 'rowexpander',
      rowBodyTpl: ['<p><b>Field 1:</b> {field1}</p><br>',
                   '<p><b>Field 2:</b> {field2}</p>']
  }]
});
```